# Windows 10 start up takes too long

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot

Issue began when I put my laptop into sleep mode for almost 1 day.

Before this everything was normal, but now my **Windows 10** has a very slow start up of almost **30-40 minutes** or more.

My Windows Defender is also having weird behavior (e.g. I can't open it, or every time after a restart Windows tells me that my firewall is off).
I installed Avira and performed a scan but my laptop's clean.

I did some research which told me to use WPRui.exe and WPA.exe. I tried it but I don't know how to read the Analyzer. Please kindly help me analyze what's wrong with my [Windows](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7IU6jWy_A5JZmxyYWtYRGVfWnc/view?usp=sharing)

This is a screenshot about my HDD condition using CrystalDisk Info :

[image: Crystal Disk Screenshot]

Comment: get CrystalDiskInfo from here https://crystalmark.info/download/index-e.html and see if your hard drives are okay.

Comment: i edited my question, pls kindly check it.. i have no idea what's those status.

Comment: Based on the status of your HDD, it appears your HDD is about to fail, you should replace it immediately.

Comment: is there any other way to fix it instead changing my HDD ?

Comment: *No*, You cannot fix the problem your HDD currently has.  You have sectors on your HDD that have failed, there isn't a way, to fix those bad sectors.

Comment: Ramhound is correct, replace the HDD as soon as possible!